# Getting the renamed name of an Android BluetoothDevice

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

My android phone allows me rename devices that I have paired with, by going to the [Settings > Wireless & Networkds > Bluetooth] Activity page and clicking the settings button to the right of a paired bluetooth device.  However, when I query for a list of Bonded devices with the [BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29) function, the name that shows up in the results is the default name for the device.

How can I access the renamed name for a Bluetooth device?

Comment: Did you try [BluetoothAdapter.getName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getName())?

Comment: I'm not looking for the name of the current Bluetooth adapter, I'm looking for the names of devices that are paired with the current adapter.

Comment: Did you found an answer to your question I'm experimenting the same problem.

Comment: Nope, still active :-)

Comment: Anybody got the solution for the same. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use **alias name**.

For setting rename device:

```
try {
    Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("setAlias", String.class);
    if(method != null) {
        method.invoke(device, "new_device_name");
    }
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For getting device name:

```
String deviceAlias = device.getName();
try {
    Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("getAliasName");
    if(method != null) {
        deviceAlias = (String)method.invoke(device);
    }
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This worked great on my nexus 7, API 22! However, setting aliases didn't work on my ViewSonic VSD241 API 17. Not sure why, no errors were thrown, it was just ignored by the system.

Comment: Hi, I'm checking it with BLE device but it say **"java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAliasName []"** Any suggestion here?

Comment: ahh,,,i was me who was making mistake. Thanks it's working great :).

Comment: It works in my Samsung Galaxy Tab, Android 4.2. I have tried other private methods (@hide attribute) and they do not work. For some odd reason getAliasName() has "@hide" coded. Unfortunately I overlooked this method with a reasonable name.

Comment: The method is now "getAlias" ... perhaps look for both?

Comment: Breaking changes in SDK 30: 
- getAliasName() was removed; 
- getAlias() got rid of @hide attribute and implemented similar to getAliasName()