# BluetoothDevice getName() to return local alias

Tags: android, bluetooth

In Android, you can give paired devices a name that is different from the advertised name from the device itself. However, if I call `getName()` on the `BluetoothDevice` I get the device's own name.

Is there a way to fetch the local alias of the device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the renamed name of an Android BluetoothDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658142/getting-the-renamed-name-of-an-android-bluetoothdevice)

Answer (score 1):

There's a hidden method `getAlias()` in `BluetoothDevice` class. You can access it via reflection as described here: [Getting the renamed name of an Android BluetoothDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658142/getting-the-renamed-name-of-an-android-bluetoothdevice).  There are no guarantees that hidden APIs will not be broken with next update to Android OS though.