# Getting the renamed bluetooth device Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to get the renamed bluetooth device using this:

```
@Override
    public void onDeviceDiscovered(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
device.getName();
}
```

But the problem is that i'm getting the wrong name or let say the device manufacturer name

Look at this :

```
/**
 * Get the friendly Bluetooth name of the remote device.
 *
 * <p>The local adapter will automatically retrieve remote names when
 * performing a device scan, and will cache them. This method just returns
 * the name for this device from the cache.
 *
 * @return the Bluetooth name, or null if there was a problem.
 */
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
public String getName() {
    final IBluetooth service = sService;
    if (service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BT not enabled. Cannot get Remote Device name");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        String name = service.getRemoteName(this);
        if (name != null) {
            return name.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]+", " ");
        }
        return null;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My question is how to return only the Bluetooth name and nothing else please help.

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658142/getting-the-renamed-name-of-an-android-bluetoothdevice

Comment: this was for getting device name not the bluetooth name